# User/pw/email Authentication for Cloudbees Docker Build and Deploy Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins, cloudbees

I've been try to use the Cloudbees Build and Deploy plugin to push a docker image to our private dockerhub repository. The documentation shows a credential type that takes user/email and pw.

When I try to setup a new Jenkins credential, I do not see this option. (Just the regular user/pw)

I'm using Jenkins 1.609.3, docker 1.7.1, Cloudbees Docker Build and Publish 1.0, CloudBees Credentials Plugin 3.3, Docker commons plugin 1.2

Version problem? Or am I missing something else.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the [wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Docker+Build+and+Publish+plugin), this seems to have been referring to the 0.x plugin versions. The [user manual](http://documentation.cloudbees.com/docs/cje-user-guide/docker-build-publish.html) should cover 1.x. I will make a note in the wiki.